# rails thin server cannot start - certificate too small

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, certificate, thin

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20, I can no longer run thin server in ssl mode:

```
thin start --ssl
```

Server starts fine but when I go to it I get:

```
140107127297856:error:140AB18F:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ee key too small:../ssl/ssl_rsa.c:310:
ruby /home/kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/thin start --ssl: ssl.cpp:203:   SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, const string&, const string&, const string&, const string&, const string&, int): Assertion `e > 0' failed.
```

I've tried modifying the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf to add

```
DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

but no luck.  Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **generate certificates** and then point to those certificates

The generated certificates(we'll get to this later ) can be saved anywhere but I'll choose to save it in a .ssl folder in the root of my project

Follow the following steps to generate the certificates

```sh
  $ openssl genrsa 2048 > host.key
  $ chmod 400 host.key
  $ openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -key host.key -out host.cert
```

the above commands will generate two files

- host.key
- host.cert

Then start your thin server by running the following command

`thin start --ssl --ssl-key-file=.ssl/host.key --ssl-cert-file=.ssl/host.cert`